# what is best approach to modify mysql password in kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

current set-up.
i created mysql pod and created users using initdb.d configmaps.

what is the best approach to change password of an user anytime in future?

thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends on the image you've used setting it up. Although as a general rule: configmaps, for passwords, isn't the best approach. Usually you would prefer Secrets, for sensitive data. While you should make sure passwords can be rotated / not all images would support this.

Comment: you can simply write the SQL and other automation scripts to rotate the password. in any case if you are using configmap or secret updating the password with SQL statement would better as secret of configmap changes required the mySQL restart unless you image support auto reloader on configmap and secret changes.

Comment: @HarshManvar. thank you.  do you have any examples? on a pod that is already deployed. what is the procedure for updating password using config. map or secrets ?
i understand that requires restart of the pod. thanks in advance